# How to bind nested type to a BindingContext in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have my ViewModel wrapped inside a complex object, I want to set up that VM as a `BindingContext` of my Xaml. Right now I am doing from code behind but I want to achieve it via Xaml.

```
var mainViewModel = this.BindingContext as AppShell;
this.BindingContext = (mainViewModel.BindingContext as MainViewModel);
```

I tried below code in my Xaml, but it's giving null value instead of VM reference.

> BindingContext={Binding MainViewModel}

Comment: `MainViewModel` is a class, bind it to the public instance of that class

Comment: @SushiHangover Could you please post the code snippet? My public instance looks something like this  `var viewModel = this.BindingContext as Shell;`

Comment: You want to give the whole page `BindingContext` ?

Comment: @Greggz No. Just to the control.

Comment: do you mean you want bind one model,and it is inside another model ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Yes

Comment: you could declare an internal model variable in the external model,for  example: `public InsideModel inside_model; ` then you  `bindcontext = outsidemodel `,then use  `binding inside_model.attribute `